# PostgreSQL connection pooling architecture

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling

I know there are two main connection pooling tools for postgresql: pgpool & pgbouncer.
We're looking for the best architecture to build the connection pooling. The main problem is how we deal when the connection pooler is down (no matter what reason), how clients can access the databases when the pgpool / pgbouncer is down? is there a way to have a "backup" for a tool like that?
Also, where should I install the connction pooler: on the main server/ slave server/ or at a different machine?
The most important in this question is how we deal when the connection pooler gets down?

Comment: The client would treat it in exactly the same way as if the database was down.

Comment: That's in case I have only regular pgpool / pgbouncer. I konw there's a way to create a 'backup' for those connection poolers. If the primary connection pooler is down the standby will be primary for now. I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the HA problem at the connection pooler level as below:

- I used two pgPool-II servers in active-passive mode to achieve high availability.
- I set up a watchdog to monitor the status of the pgPool-II servers and switch them if needed.
- I created a virtual IP that would always point to the active pgPool-II server. It can be configured using `delegate_IP` parameter in pgPool-II config file.

The architecture would look somethiing like:
[image: pgpool-II HA Architecture]

Please let me know if you would like to have more implementation level detail on this.